# Where is JVMTI's Breakpoint event called?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

I cloned OpenJDK8's source code and wanted to check where exactly JVMTI's `Breakpoint` callback is called. What I found is that all the breakpoints are stored in a list of type `JvmtiBreakpoint`. What I couldn't find was where exactly the breakpoint events are fired.

Edit: I found this method, but not sure if this fires the event:

```
JvmtiExport::post_raw_breakpoint
```

Which is called by:

```
 InterpreterRuntime:_breakpoint
```

which lead me to the `bytecodeInterpreter.cpp` file, where this method is called. In this file we have:

```
    switch (opcode):
      ...
      CASE(_breakpoint): {
      ...
      CALL_VM(InterpreterRuntime::_breakpoint(THREAD, METHOD, pc),  handle_exception);
      ...}
```

But I still don't understand what happens when I place a breakpoint in the code? Does the JVM instrument the bytecode at that location and place a breakpoint opcode?

Edit2: I found out that when setting a breakpoint, eventually

```
Method::set_breakpoint
```

is called.

Comment: Please don't include "thanks" or " Can you help me with this please?". See here for more: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: The answer to this question likely depends on if the jvm is interpreting the code in question, or if it had JIT'ed the code. Do you care about both cases?

Comment: @PiRocks For my use case, I am only interested when the app is run in debug mode. Is JIT activated in that case?

Comment: What do you mean by "run in debug mode"? JIT absolutely can be activated while the app is being debugged. Some vms can breakpoint in jit'ed code, I'm not certain how things work in hotspot

Comment: @PiRocks yeah, I thought JIT is not activated in debug mode. But activating a breakpoint in JITed code is interesting, didn't know about that...